# Hudson multi-project configuration

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

My goal is to build war file and copy (deploy) in remote machines.

What I have to do is I have one Subversion and two locations one 'Trunk' and 'Branch'. I have three remote machines.

My ideas:

1. Creating 6 (2 X 3) jobs in Hudson. But problem is my project size is 512MB, so for 6 jobs, it becomes 6 X 512 MB. It is very big size, my system can not help me.
2. Creating one job for Trunk and one job for Branch and machine parameters we have to pass parameters dynamically regarding remote machine. It looks good, but I have basic knowledge of Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

For your second options, you can take pom file as a parameter (may be a choice param).

Also, look upon [Publish Over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin), it supports parameterized publishing.